# Is there any way we can hide url on Iphone browser using Url_launcher plugin

Tags: webview, flutter

I'm using Url_launcher plugin to open some specific URL but I don't want to show URL to the user. In Android, the Adress bar doesn't show up but in IOS it does. Is there any way to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

As the url_launcher documentation says:

> By default, Android opens up a browser when handling URLs. You can
>   pass forceWebView: true parameter to tell the plugin to open a WebView
>   instead. On iOS, the default behavior is to open all web URLs within
>   the app. Everything else is redirected to the app handler.

So iOS opens urls inside a WebView already. But.. you must be sure to enable Flutter embedded views on your Info.plist. You need to add a boolean property with:

```
key = io.flutter.embedded_views_preview
value = YES
```

And that should do the job.

For more info you can take a look at this issue.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19030

Comment: Tried this already but doesn't seem to work, It still shows address bar on top of the page like  safari browser

Comment: And it doesn't show up inside the webview, I'm using Url_launcher plugin for some specific URL and also the plugin for webview I'm using is flutter_webview_plugin not flutter_webview.